# Explanation of a Mechanical Situation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

[image]

The box sitting on the table top has some mass $m$ (I would refer to the weight of the box just as $\mathbf{W}$), and its net acceleration which I call $\mathbf{a}$ is zero, for the time being. This means

$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathbf{W} + \mathbf{F} + \mathbf{R}}{m} = \mathbf{a} = 0\\
\Rightarrow \mathbf{W} = -(\mathbf{F} + \mathbf{R})
\end{equation}$$

Now, the greater the $\mathbf{F}$ is, the less is $\mathbf{W_{T}}$ on the table, and consequently the less is $\mathbf{R}$ on the box. And this is because some fraction of $\mathbf{W}$ is also balancing the force by my hand so long as $\mathbf{a}=0$. But when $\mathbf{R}=0$,
$$\mathbf{W} = -\mathbf{F},$$

which means that now there is no force on the table by the box, ***but the box is still on the table*** because $\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{F}=0$, that is the net force on the box is zero and hence $\mathbf{a}$ too is zero. ***Is that correct (or real)?***

Now, when $\mathbf{F}$ is greater, in magnitude of course, than $\mathbf{W}$, then the box has an upward acceleration, that is $\mathbf{a} \neq 0$, so let the net force on the box be $\mathbf{F}_{net}$, which can be given as

$$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{net} = \mathbf{W}+\mathbf{F} = m\mathbf{a} = m(\frac{\mathbf{F}}{m}-\mathbf{g})\\
\Rightarrow \mathbf{a} = \frac{\mathbf{F}}{m}-\mathbf{g}.
\end{equation}$$

So is this a correct explanation of what would happen normally in this situation?

Comment: This is in no way a homework-like question and you can see the effort. I have put in what I knew and had thought. That is clearly unfair.

Answer (score 1):

> which means that now there is no force on the table by the box, but
>   the box is still on the table because $W+F=0$, that is the net force on
>   the box is zero and hence $a$ too is zero. Is that correct (or real)?

Almost. Technically, if $R$ is zero, the box is not *on* the table. It has infinitesimally lost contact with the table, and the lifting force is totally supporting the mass.  This is often how we solve problems of limiting forces or limiting speeds: find the point at which the normal force ($R$) goes to zero.

The final part ($\textbf{a}\ne 0$) is correct.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the box has changed its position which would mean it accelerated?

Comment: Slightly, for a moment, but for $R$ to go to zero the mass must move away from the surface. Looking at your line of thought in the comment, the mass accelerates every time $R$ changes because the interaction of the surfaces depends on the relative positions of the two surface structures.

Comment: Do you mean it has a non-zero net acceleration every time $R$ changes?